# How to define a list which evaluates to the sequence [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), etc.] and [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), etc.]

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell and i was wondering how can you define two lists one of which which evaluates to the sequence [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), etc.] and the other one to  [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), etc.]? I had multiple tries but every time it just prints out the first sequence and doesn't print the second one. If someone could show me how that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Can you let us know what you have tried ? We can help you better if we know the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: Hint: `[0..]`, `zip`, and `repeat` can be used to solve this problem.  You could also solve it with `map` instead of `zip` and `repeat`.  If you're going to use `map`, think of what function would turn `n` into `(n, 0)`, and similarly what function would turn `n` into `(0, n)`?

Comment: alt. Hint: instead of map you might want to try list-comprehensions - this task can easily be solved with those and it's very close to the problem - for example play with this a bit: `[ x*x | x <- [0..] ]`

Comment: [(i,j) | i <- [0,1], j <- [0..]] i think that should do it but it gives me an error unexpected '|' and i don't know why.

Comment: Funny, if I copy-paste that into tryhaskell.org it works fine.

Comment: Thanks will see about that error

Comment: Thank you S.L Barth for showing me that very useful tool. I completed the task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an infinite list of zeros with:

```
[0, 0 ..]
```

and you can define an infinite list of integers starting at `0` in a similar way:

```
[0, 1 ..]
```

The function `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` takes two lists and 'zips' them into a list of tuples. So if we combine zip with the above list notation, we can achieve what you ask:

```
zip [0, 0 ..] [0, 1 ..]
```

You can try this in ghci:

```
> take 4 $ zip [0, 0 ..] [0, 1 ..]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
> take 4 $ zip [0, 1 ..] [0, 0 ..]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
```

#### using list-comprehensions

```
[ (i,0) | i <- [0..] ]
```

and

```
[ (0,i) | i <- [0..] ]
```

Comment: So [(i,j) | i <- [0,1], j <- [0..]] this is not the right way to do it. Can you tell me what is wrong with this one. Sorry for the basic questions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, it's just different syntax. I personally find the list comprehension syntax a little cryptic, so I like the version with `zip`. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: I did it with list comprehension anyways. Thanks for the help from everyone :)

Comment: I hope it is ok if I append the version with the comprehensions - @Charlie please accept this answer so we can close this question - thanks